# How to filter a response based on an extra foreign key in a many-to-many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

I'm having a difficult time with this many-to-many relationship in Laravel. I have a many-to-many relationship, projects and persons. I also have a third table, roles (with 2 columns: id, name), which contains roles a person can have on a project (in this case, "actor", "director", etc). The pivot table, person_project, has the columns "person_id", "project_id", and "role_id". I had success getting all the persons associated with a project using

```php
$project = Project::find($id);
$project->persons;
```

But how can I just get persons with a specific role on a project? And how would I save such a relationship?

Models:

```php
// Project.php

class Project extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'projects';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function persons() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Person');
    }
}

// Person.php

class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'persons';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.developed.be/2013/08/30/laravel-4-pivot-table-example-attach-and-detach/) was helpful in figuring out the retrieving of the relationship. Eloquent's withPivot() and join() methods were key in getting it to work.

```php
// In the Project model

public function persons() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Person')
                ->withPivot('role_id')
                ->join('roles', 'role_id', '=', 'roles.id');
}
```

I figured out the insertion part from Laravel's docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models
In this example, Input::get('directors') is an array of person_ids selected to be connected to the role of "director". The same deal for Input::get('actors').

```php
// Within the update method of the Projects controller

foreach (Input::get('directors') as $directorId) {
    $project->persons()->attach($directorId, array('role_id' => 1)); // roles.id 1 = "director"
}

foreach (Input::get('actors') as $actorId) {
    $project->persons()->attach($actorId, array('role_id' => 2)); // roles.id 2 = "actor"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

If you are using **Laravel 4.1**:

```
$project = Project::whereHas('persons', function($q)
{
    $q->where('role_id', 1);

})->get();
```

**Laravel 4 and 4.1:**

```
$project = Project::with(array('persons' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('role_id', 1);
}))->get();
```